# Importing CSV using LOAD DATA INFILE quote problem

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I'm trying to get this CSV file that I exported from excel loaded into my database and I can't seem to get the formatting correct no matter what I try.

Here is the SQL:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/file.csv'
INTO TABLE tbl_name 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(column1, column2, column3);
```

This works fine but then I run into trouble when the end of a line (column 3) ends in a quote. For example:

Actual value: `These are "quotes"`

Value in CSV: `"These are ""quotes"""`

What happens is that I will get an extra quote on that value in the database and also any additional lines until it reaches another quote in the CSV. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hmm. I tried to duplicate this problem but can't. Where does my data differ from yours? Can you provide sample data to duplicate this? Here's what I did:

```
> cat /tmp/data.csv
"aaaa","bbb ""ccc"" ddd",xxx
xxx,yyy,"zzz ""ooo"""
foo,bar,baz

mysql> CREATE TABLE t2 (a varchar(20), b varchar(20), c varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/data.csv' INTO TABLE t2 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (a, b, c);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from t2;
+------+---------------+-----------+
| a    | b             | c         |
+------+---------------+-----------+
| aaaa | bbb "ccc" ddd | xxx       |
| xxx  | yyy           | zzz "ooo" |
| foo  | bar           | baz       |
+------+---------------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Looks ok to me(?)

Also note that if you're working on a Windows platform you might need to use
`LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! The issue was that I needed to use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` instead.

Comment: Great answer, I tried exactly what you have above, but get the error ERROR 29 (HY000): File '/tmp/data.csv' not found (Errcode: 13), I also tried to add load data local infile but got the error ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version I am using 5.5.34 and the permissions on my temp folder are drwxrwxrwt is there anything else I need to check here to get this working?

Comment: @ak85 That usually happens when the MySQL server is not on the same host as the client where you're running those commands. Realize it's the server that needs to load the data, not the client. So if you're connecting to a remote server then you can't import data like this unless you upload the data to the server first.

Comment: Thanks for the info so if I enter select host from information_schema.processlist \G and get host: localhost and when in ubuntu my file is /tmp/data.csv so I believe I would have the same setup as you?  cat /tmp/data.csv works like your eg but no luck importing. I will keep investigating

Comment: I was loading data from .txt file and had problems. I was sure that `\r\n` wasn't the issue but I finnaly gave up and tried it..., aaaaand it worked.