# Fastest way to import csv file into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

This method uploads csv file to mysql .But upon thousands of data in csv file it takes lots of time to upload the data which is annoying.

```
        $deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE discount"; //empty the table of its current records
        mysql_query($deleterecords);
        //readfile($name);
        //Import uploaded file to Database
        $handle = fopen($name, "r");

        $i=0;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if($i>0){
            $import="INSERT into discount(id,title,expired_date,amount,block)values('".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."','".$data[2]."','".$data[3]."','".$data[4]."')";
        //imports data serially to the allocated columns.
            mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());//query
        }
        $i=1;
        }
        fclose($handle);
       //closing the handle
       // print "Import done ";
       ?>

Can anyone suggest faster method for uploading data ?
```

Comment: Read [`LOAD DATA INFILE ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019506/importing-csv-using-load-data-infile-quote-problem

Comment: Please note that you are using a deprecated library to access your db. Instead of myslq_ (that will be removed in the next versions of php) use mysqli_ or even better PDO!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert data this way. This is default way to insert rows in a table.

```
    $deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE discount"; //empty the table of its current records
    mysql_query($deleterecords);
    //readfile($name);

    //Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($name, "r");

    $i=0;

    $ins = "INSERT into discount(id,title,expired_date,amount,block) values ";

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    if($i>0){

    $import .= $ins."('".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."','".$data[2]."','".$data[3]."','".$data[4]."'),";
    //imports data serially to the allocated columns.

    }

    $import = rtrim($import,',');
    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());//query
    $i=1;
    }
    fclose($handle);
   //closing the handle
   // print "Import done ";
   ?>
```

Comment: You should strip the last comma at the end of $import string, before mysql_query().

Answer (score 6):

Instead of writing a script to pull in information from a CSV file, you can link MYSQL directly to it and upload the information using the following SQL syntax.

To import an Excel file into MySQL, first export it as a CSV file. Remove the CSV headers from the generated CSV file along with empty data that Excel may have put at the end of the CSV file.

You can then import it into a MySQL table by running:

```
load data local infile 'uniq.csv' into table tblUniq fields terminated by ','
  enclosed by '"'
  lines terminated by '\n'
    (uniqName, uniqCity, uniqComments)
```

as read on: [Import CSV file directly into MySQL](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2345/import_csv_file_directly_into_mysql/)

Comment: This is by far faster than loading row by row and when it comes to speed should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the LOAD DATA INFILE statement.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Load the data in a temporary table and use that for inserting to your main table with one statement.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having multiple insert, build a big query and execute a single insert.

```
<?php
$deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE discount"; //empty the table of its current records
mysql_query($deleterecords);
//readfile($name);
//Import uploaded file to Database
$handle = fopen($name, "r");

$i=0;
$what_to_insert = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if($i>0){
        array_push($what_to_insert, "('".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."','".$data[2]."','".$data[3]."','".$data[4]."')");
    }
    $i=1;
}
fclose($handle);
if (count($what_to_insert)>0){
    $import="INSERT into discount(id,title,expired_date,amount,block) values " . implode(",", $what_to_insert);
    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());//query
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If phpMyAdmin is available you can use the CSV import feature.