# How to use textfile to create SQL table entries?

Tags: php, mysql, database, web, crash-reports

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
WPG GRIFFON, WIREHAIRED 
AFG HOUND, AFGHAN 
IBI HOUND, IBIZAN 
WOF HOUND, IRISH WOLF 
OTT HOUND, OTTER 
PHA HOUND, PHAROAH 
DER HOUND, SCOTTISH DEER 
JIN JINDO 
...
```

and I am trying to rewrite this line of code so it says the names of the dogs

```
$link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db) or die(mysqli_error($link));

mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `description` (`descID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `desc` text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`descID`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;");
```

mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `description` (`descID`, `desc`) VALUES(1, 'description 1'),(2, 'description 2'),(3, 'description 3'),(4, 'description 4');");

However, I always get an error and it crashes the webpage, because I can't get the file to be read and saved.

```
$handle = @fopen("names.txt", "r");
while (!feof($handle)) // Loop til end of file.
{
$buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);

$sql = "INSERT INTO data_table ...."  
mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Care to share the error message with us?

Comment: Add this `if ( mysqli_query($link, _CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `description` (`descID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `desc` text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`descID`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;") === false ) echo mysqli_error($link);_ to get the error message generated!'

Comment: Add an if statement around the query like `if ( mysqli_query($link` ... ) === false ) echo mysqli_error( $link);`  _(Can not use apostrophs in comments)_

Comment: There is no specific error message, I am trying to write a line of code that opens the text file, reads the lines, and makes a `mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `description` (`descID`, `desc`) VALUES(1, 'description 1'),(2, 'description 2'),(3, 'description 3'),(4, 'description 4');");` to be `mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `description` (`descID`, `desc`) VALUES(1, 'WPG GRIFFON, WIREHAIRED '),(2, 'AFG HOUND, AFGHAN),(3, 'IBI HOUND, IBIZAN'),(4, 'WOF HOUND, IRISH WOLF');");`

Comment: without error message all i can say your web page is crashing so you should just make it not crashable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you **need** to use `INSERT` statements? There are two other very viable options (a little out of the box, maybe):

1. `LOAD DATA`: SQL that loads pre-built CSV data into a table. See [the MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019506/importing-csv-using-load-data-infile-quote-problem)

Example usage (from the linked SO thread):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/file.csv'
INTO TABLE tbl_name 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(column1, column2, column3);
```

2. `mysqlimport`: If you have access to the MySql shell, you can use this to import a physical CSV to the db. See [the MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) or [this post from a random google click](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/mysql/w/wiki/6152.mysql-importing-with-mysqlimport)