# Load Data Infile OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Many related tickets and tut sites but unfortunately no solutions have worked for me so far, couple hours stuck on this.

I have many csv files I need to insert into a mysql db, using 'load in file' does it very quickly and easily.

However, it stumbles on one section:
Sample csv line:

> ABSOLUTE,Glenn,Anakie,"Cool Synd, Super Cool"

Code I'm using is:

```
$q = "load data infile '$file' into table $table
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';";
    mysql_query($q, $db);
```

I expect to have 4 fields from this, but I end up with 5, it counts the comma inside the quotes as being a delimiter. I thought the point of OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY was to catch these cases?

I've tried switching the order of the field terminated and opt enclosed by commands. Tried just making it ENCLOSED BY. Tried not escaping the ", also /"/", tried using 2 single quotes instead of a double; but I still can't get it to understand that I want "Cool Synd, Super Cool" as one field.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is my table structure:

[image]

I simply throw all my data in here then I process it and move fields to the relevant tables into the correct format. The column with the problem is 'Owner'.
I've changed it to text type here as that was the solution for others, but it works the same way whether it is text, char, varchar, etc.

(Working on Ubuntu server 14.4, Apache/2.4.7, PHP 5.5.9)

Comment: Did you remove \ in OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' so it would look like this OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ? https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:24126417179833

Comment: I did but that will throw a php syntax error. I need to escape the double quote as being a special character for it to run.

Comment: I think the one that is causing the error is the colon(;); Try to remove the colon in the last part. like this: "load data infile '$file' into table $table
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't work, but (off topic) surprisingly mySQL doesn't blow up. Thought I needed a ; there to end the query.

Comment: are you using windows platform? Also note that if you're working on a Windows platform you might need to use
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019506/importing-csv-using-load-data-infile-quote-problem

Comment: Using ubuntu server 14.4, will update description sorry. All other parts of the import work perfectly, it's just the commas inside quotes that it is acting unexpectedly on.

Comment: Can you post your table structure?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem and solved it here:

https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=366658

Just reverse the order.

```
$q = "load data infile '$file' into table $table
    FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';";
    mysql_query($q, $db);
```

You don't need the backslash before the doublequote either